# .play() for audio tags lag on iOS (and possibly other mobile devices)

Tags: ios, html5-audio

I am attempting to rebuild a game that works on itch to be compatible on most major devices and browsers. I have a problem where on iOS (and possibly other mobile devices) a call to play audio tags from click and touch events has quite a significant delay.

I have read about several potential causes, including the 300ms delay, preventDefault for the second click event, stopPropagation for potential parent clicks, different audio formats causing lag in decompression, etc. Nothing seems to work.

Initially my intent was to keep everything in vanilla js without outside libraries to force myself to really learn what's going on under the hood. However, I have been having some success with some outside libraries for other problems, so I tried fastclick.js for this problem. That didn't work for me either. So, if someone knows how to address this issue without a library that would be great, but after looking at the fastclick code, that may be beyond my level of comprehension.

A current build can be found at www.teachersteve.net/assett_loading_with_ian/assett_loading_with_ian.html

Some explanation of my thought process:

1. I removed anything that is actually game related to try and isolate the problem. I put all the assetts directly in the html to simplify the loading process and wait to start the js after the DOM loaded

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", doSomething);
   ```
2. I am currently only calling one audio tag to play as I read somewhere that calling multiple tags can overload the decompression process and cause a delay. That seems to not be the issue.
3. I have 3 different file formats so far for compatibility attempts... I did read that LEI16 (a wav format) might be best because it eliminates compression, although I haven't tried it yet.
4. This is the rest of the doSomething() function

   ```
   function doSomething() {
     document.body.style.opacity = 1;
     document.addEventListener("click", playAudio);
     document.addEventListener('click', preventInputDefault);
     document.addEventListener('ontouchend', preventInputDefault);
     console.log("assetts loaded");

     if ('addEventListener' in document) {
       document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
           FastClick.attach(document.body);
       }, false);
     }


     function playAudio() {

             // backgroundMusic.play();

         letterAudio.play();

         // correctAnswerAudio.play();

         // letterAudio.play();
         // correctAnswerAudio.play();
     }

     function preventInputDefault(evt) {
       evt.preventDefault();
       console.log("hello preventInputDefault");
       evt.stopPropagation();
       console.log("hello stopPropagation");
     }
   }
   ```

Thanks!